# i cant find where is javascript code

Tags: javascript, html

I have some problem! On my website at the bottom of page after footer tag is shown this code is there. I try load this link into my browser and it cannot be loaded!

```
<script 
    type="text/javascript" 
    src="http://example.com/adserver/static/p/10048/inimage_s.js">
</script>
```

i try find in my files but I couldn't find! Problem is that this file cannot be loaded because this file doesn't exist on this server and my other files load very slow!I try load website in Firefox and this code is not shown!

How can I find this code(this js file) or disable it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the exact same problem. There should be some kind of extension/adware/whatever causing that.
I've reported it here: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=139634

Answer (score 2):

Do you have some extension called Fast save 1.1 or Domain Error Assistant 1.0 in your chrome extensions? When I disable these extensions, error didn't happen again.

EDIT:

I have never installed these extension - there's also no information on it in the Chrome web store.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the link it has something to do with advertisements. This would imply you are loading a script somewhere else in your files which has to do with that.

If you don't add this script yourself, it should not be blocking the load of your website, only the load of the file and that should not cause any issues for you.

Try looking in your code to find for advertisements (you probably know if you did this anywhere or not).

No advertisements? Then look at all the other scripts you include that might cause this, and target the one who did and see if you really need this script or not.

Can't find that either? Perhaps it is your browser including the script. Or you might have some sort of virus lying around anywhere on your machine.

Answer (score -1):

Put this link in your browser :

```
http://overlay.mediads.info:8080/adserver/static/p/10048/inimage_s.js
```

And download the JS file( Save the File). If you want to disable it simple remove the link from your page.

Answer (score -2):

Well, you can disable the load simply by removing this line of code form your file.

I can load this js file without a problem, this is the code:

```
/** Bind for this object Function **/
if( typeof Function.prototype.bind != 'function' ){
   Function.prototype.bind = function (bind) {
       var self = this;
       return function () {
           var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
           return self.apply(bind || null, args);
       };
   };
}
/******************************** ver. 0.1F8.731 Cortica Default Object ********************************************************/
var CorticaDO = {
    version                 : 073,
    height                  : 210,
    width                   : 190,
    bannerType              : 15,
    publisherId             : 10048,
    dataUrl                 : "http://srv.overlay-ad.com:8080/adserver/Server",
    dotClickUrl             : "http://srv.overlay-ad.com:8080/adserver/inimageclick",
    requestId               : '',
    fontfamily              : "arial,helvetica,sans-serif",
    textsize                : 10,
    opacity                 : 9,// from 1 to 10
    floaters                : [],
    scanedImages            : [],
    fzindex                 : 999998, // 999998
    rescanParamExt          : "",
    rescan                  : 0,
    REC                     : 0,
    debugMode               : true,
    doRescan                : false,
    onReload                : false,
    /** Object Common Functions *********************************************************/
    /** Detect Parameters **/
    getParameterByName : function(identifier,name) {
        var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script') ,i , curScript;
        for (i = 0; i < scripts.length; ++i)
        {
            curScript = scripts[i];
            if (curScript.src.match(identifier))
            {
                name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
                var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
                var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
                var results = regex.exec((curScript.src.match(/\?.*/) || [undefined])[0]);
                if(results == null)
                    {return "";}
                else{return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));}
            }
        }
        return ;
    },
    /** Decode URL ***/
    urlDecode : function(psEncodeString){
        var lsRegExp = /\+/g;                                           /* Create a regular expression to search all +s in the string */
        return unescape(String(psEncodeString).replace(lsRegExp, " ")); /* Return the decoded string */
    },
    /** Count Object Properties **///////
    countProperties : function(obj){
        var count = 0;
        for(var prop in obj){if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)){++count;}}
        return count;
    },
    /** Debug Mode ***/
    consoleOut : function(msg){if(this.debugMode && typeof console != 'undefined' && typeof console.log === 'function'){console.log(msg);}},
    /******************************** Images Detection ************************************************************************************/
    /** Check Image ***/
    checkImageParam : function(obj){
        if(obj.height > this.height && obj.width > this.width)
            {return true;}      
        else{return false;}
    },
    /** Get Visible Images ***/
    getAllVisibleImages : function(){
        var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img'),
            i,
            tmpFloater = null,
            newImages = [];
        /* Preset Floaters */
        for(i=0; i < CorticaDO.floaters.length; i++)
            {CorticaDO.floaters[i].visible = false;}
        /* Over Images */
        if(typeof images != 'undefined')
        {
            for( var s in images)
            {
                if(CorticaDO.checkImageParam(images[s]) && CorticaDO.isVisible( images[s]))
                {
                    var found = false;
                    /* Detect Object exist */
                    if( CorticaDO.floaters.length > 0) 
                    {
                        for(i = 0; i < CorticaDO.floaters.length; i++){

                            if( CorticaDO.floaters[i].isObj(images[s]))
                            {
                                CorticaDO.floaters[i].visible = true; /* Object detected and must be visible */
                                found = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    /* New Object Add */
                    if( !found)
                    {
                        tmpFloater = new corticaFDOC();
                        tmpFloater.src = images[s].src;
                        tmpFloater.obj = images[s];
                        tmpFloater.visible = true;
                        tmpFloater.index = CorticaDO.floaters.length;
                        CorticaDO.floaters.push( tmpFloater );
                        /* New Images Array for Request to AdServer */
                        this.scanedImages.push({src:images[s].src,obj:images[s],index:tmpFloater.index});
                        newImages.push( tmpFloater ); 
                    }
                }
            }
            if(newImages.length > 0)
            {
                this.getImageList(newImages);
                this.sendScanedData();
            }
            /* Show/Hide Floaters */
            if( CorticaDO.floaters.length > 0) 
            {
                for(i=0;i< CorticaDO.floaters.length;i++)
                    {CorticaDO.floaters[i].setVisibility();}
            }
        }
    },
    /** Check Image Visibility ***/
    isVisible : function(element){
        if( element.offsetWidth === 0 || element.offsetHeight === 0)
            {return false;}
        // Resolution for IE 9/8 quirk/compatible mode
        var rects = element.getClientRects(),height,r,in_viewport;
        if('innerWidth' in window)
            {height = document.documentElement.clientHeight}
        else{height = document.body.clientHeight;}
        for( var i = 0, l = rects.length; i < l; i++)
        {
            r = rects[i];
            in_viewport = parseInt( r.top) > 0 ? parseInt( r.top) <= height : ( parseInt( r.bottom) > 0 && parseInt( r.bottom) <= height );
            if( in_viewport && CorticaDO.isElementOnTop( r, element))
                {return true;}
        }
        return false;
    },
    /** Is view Point on Element **/
    isElementOnTop : function( r, element){
        var x = parseInt(( r.left + r.right)/2),
            y = parseInt(( r.bottom + r.top)/2);
        var el = document.elementFromPoint( x, y);
        if( typeof el == 'undefined' || el == null)
            {return false}
        return (el === element);
    },
    /** Preset Image and Data Image Functions **/ /** tu - tag url,ts - tag size, ta - tag alt, tt - tag title **/
    getImageList : function(list){
        var lsRegExp    = /\+/g,
            tu = "",ts = "&sizes=",ta = "&alts=",tt = "&titles=";
        for(var img=0;img<list.length;img++)
        {
            var tiUrl   = escape(list[img].src);
            tiUrl       = tiUrl.replace(lsRegExp, encodeURIComponent('+'));
            tu += tiUrl + "|";
            ts += list[img].obj.width + "x" + list[img].obj.height + "|";
            var alt = list[img].obj.getAttribute('alt');
            var title = list[img].obj.getAttribute('title');
            if(typeof alt == 'string')
                {ta += escape(alt.replace (/\|/g, " ")) + "|";}
            else{ta += "|";}
            if(typeof title == 'string')
                {tt += escape(title.replace (/\|/g, " ")) + "|";}
            else{tt += "|";}
        }
        this.rescanParamExt = tu+ts+ta+tt+"&rescan="+this.rescan+"&requesId="+this.requestId;
    },
    /******************************************************************************************************************************/
    /** Start Main Flow **/
    corticaScan : function(){
        if(CorticaDO.onRescan || CorticaDO.onReload){return;}
        CorticaDO.onRescan = true;
        CorticaDO.getAllVisibleImages();
        CorticaDO.onRescan = false; 
    },
    /** Common Start Flows Function **/
    applyCortica : function(data,reqID){
        CorticaDO.onReload = true;
        this.requestId = reqID;
        var dataCount = this.countProperties(data),found,i;
        if(dataCount > 0)
        {
            for(var img = 0;img < dataCount;img++)
            {
                var src = unescape(data[img].imageUrl);
                for( var p in this.scanedImages)
                {
                    found = false;
                    for(i=0;i < CorticaDO.floaters.length;i++)
                    {   
                        if( CorticaDO.floaters[i].src == src && CorticaDO.floaters[i].floater == null && this.scanedImages[p].index == CorticaDO.floaters[i].index)
                        {
                            CorticaDO.floaters[i].parseData(data[img]);
                            CorticaDO.floaters[i].createOFloater();
                            CorticaDO.floaters[i].viewFloater();
                            found = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if(found){break;}
                }
            }
        }
        CorticaDO.onReload = false;
    },
    /** Send Images to AdServer **/
    sendScanedData : function(){
        try{
            this.consoleOut('\nReload');// Debug Only
            this.requestId  = '';
            if(typeof this.REC.removeScriptTag == 'function')
            {
                this.REC.removeScriptTag();                             // Delete from Header corticaData
                this.REC    = 0;
            }
            //
            CorticaDO.REC   = new CorticaJSONscriptRequest(CorticaDO.dataUrl,'btype='+CorticaDO.bannerType+'&rid='+CorticaDO.publisherId+'&ref='+escape(document.location.href)+'&imgs='+CorticaDO.rescanParamExt);
            CorticaDO.REC.buildScriptTag();
            CorticaDO.REC.addScriptTag();
            CorticaDO.onReload       = false;
            CorticaDO.refUrl         = "";
            CorticaDO.rescanParamExt = '';
            CorticaDO.rescan++;
        }
        catch(err)
        {
            this.REC        = 0;
            this.consoleOut(err); // Debug Only
        }
    },
    /** Event Close Floater ***/
    closeFloater : function(p){
        if(document.getElementById('corticaOF'+ p))
        {
            document.getElementById('corticaOF'+ p).style.display = 'none';
            CorticaDO.floaters[p].disable = true;
        }
        else{this.consoleOut('Can\'t find floater for close action with ID: corticaOF'+p);}
    },
};
/** Floater Default Object Clone *********************************************************************************************************************/
function corticaFDOC(){
    this.obj        = null;
    this.src        = '';
    this.visible    = true;
    this.index      = null;
    this.data       = {styleID:1,behaviour:2,advertiserId:10,campaignId:0,siteId:1,html:null,banW:null,banH:null,nonloc:1,isFullWidth:0,content:3};
    this.floater    = null;
    this.onOFView   = false;
    this.disable    = false;
};
corticaFDOC.prototype = {
    /** Create Overlay Floater ***/
    createOFloater : function (){
        var self            = this;
        var f               = document.createElement('DIV');
        if(this.data.isFullWidth == 0)
            {f.style.width  = this.data.banW + "px";}
        else{f.style.width  = this.obj.width + "px";}
        f.style.height      = this.data.banH + "px";
        f.invoker           = this.obj;
        f.style.position    = 'absolute';
        f.style.display     = 'none';
        f.style.cursor      = 'pointer';
        f.style.overflow    = 'hidden';
        f.style.fontFamily  = CorticaDO.fontfamily;
        f.style.padding     = f.style.margin = 0;
        f.innerHTML         = this.data.html;
        f.setAttribute('id','corticaOF'+this.index);
        document.body.appendChild(f);
        /** Set Close Button **/
        if(document.getElementById('corticaFcl'))
        {
            var fclb = document.getElementById('corticaFcl');
            fclb.id = "corticaFcl"+this.index;
            fclb.onclick = function()
                {CorticaDO.closeFloater(self.index);};//this.closeFloater(self.index).bind(this);
        }
        this.floater = f;
    },
    /** Parse Data from AdServer ***/
    parseData : function (data){
        if(typeof data['behaviorId'] != 'undefined')    {this.data.behaviour  = data['behaviorId'];}
        if(typeof data['loc'] != 'undefined')           {this.data.nonloc   = data['loc'];}             // Non Locationable
        if(typeof data['siteId'] != 'undefined')        {this.data.siteId   = data['siteId'];}
        if(typeof data['isFullWidth'] != 'undefined')   {this.data.isFullWidth= data['isFullWidth'];}   // isFullWidth
        if(typeof data['content'] != 'undefined')       {this.data.content  = data['content'];}         // content
        // Set data to object
        if(typeof data['ads'][0].html != 'undefined'){
            this.data.html              = CorticaDO.urlDecode(data['ads'][0].html);
            if(typeof data['ads'][0].bannerWidth != 'undefined')                        // banW
                {this.data.banW         = data['ads'][0].bannerWidth;}
            if(typeof data['ads'][0].bannerHeight != 'undefined')                       // banH
                {this.data.banH         = data['ads'][0].bannerHeight;}
            if(typeof data['ads'][0].styleId != 'undefined' && data['ads'][0].styleId)
                {this.data.styleID      = data['ads'][0].styleId;}
            if(data['ads'][0].advertiserId)
                {this.data.advertiserId = data['ads'][0].advertiserId;}
            if(data['ads'][0].campaignId)
                {this.data.campaignId   = data['ads'][0].campaignId;}
        }
    },
    /** Show Floater ***/
    viewFloater: function (){
        try{
            if(typeof this.data != 'undefined')
            {
                var allOffset   = this.getOffsetElement(this.obj);
                var strH    = this.floater.style.height;
                var strW    = this.floater.style.width;
                if(this.floater.style.display != "block" && !this.disable){
                    if(this.data.nonloc == 3)
                        {this.floater.style.top = (allOffset.top + this.obj.height) + 'px';}
                    else{this.floater.style.top = (allOffset.top + this.obj.height - parseInt(strH.replace(/px/i, ""),10)) + 'px';}
                    var left = 0;
                    if(this.data.isFullWidth == 0)
                        {left                   = parseInt((this.obj.width - parseInt(strW.replace(/px/i, ""),10))/2);}
                    this.floater.style.left     = allOffset.left + left + 'px';
                    this.floater.style.zIndex   = CorticaDO.fzindex;
                    this.floater.style.display  = 'block';
                    if(!this.onOFView)
                    {
                        this.onOFView = true;
                        this.doclick(0);
                    }
                }
            }       
        }
        catch(err){CorticaDO.consoleOut(err);}
    },
    /** Position Correction ***/
    correctPos : function (){
        if(this.floater != null)
        {
            var allOffset   = this.getOffsetElement(this.obj);
            var strH    = this.floater.style.height;
            var strW    = this.floater.style.width;
            if(this.data.nonloc == 3)
                {this.floater.style.top = (allOffset.top + this.obj.height) + 'px';}
            else{this.floater.style.top = (allOffset.top + this.obj.height - parseInt(strH.replace(/px/i, ""),10)) + 'px';}
            var left = 0;
            if(this.data.isFullWidth == 0)
                {left                   = parseInt((this.obj.width - parseInt(strW.replace(/px/i, ""),10))/2);}
            this.floater.style.left = allOffset.left + left + 'px';             
        }
    },
    /** Close Floater ***/
    closeFloater : function(){
        if(document.getElementById('corticaOF'+ this.index))
        {
            document.getElementById('corticaOF'+ this.index).style.display = 'none';
            this.disable = true;
        }
        else{CorticaDO.consoleOut('Can\'t find floater for close action with ID: corticaOF'+this.index);}
    },
    /** Get Visibility Status ***/
    isVisible : function(){return this.visible;},
    /** Hide Floater **/
    hide : function(){this.toggle(false);},
    /** Show Floater **/
    display : function(){this.toggle(true);},
    /** Show/Hide Floaters [action: true/false] ***/
    toggle : function(action){
        var status = action ? "block" : "none";
        if(!this.disable)
        {
            if(document.getElementById('corticaOF'+this.index))
                {document.getElementById('corticaOF'+this.index).style.display = status;}
            if(action)
                {this.correctPos();}
        }
    },
    setVisibility : function(){
        if(this.floater != null)
            {this.visible ? this.display() : this.hide();}
    },
    /** Check if obj Same **/
    isObj : function (obj){return this.src == obj.src && this.obj === obj;},
    /** Report ver 0.9 **/
    doclick : function(dotIndex){
        var  requester  = new Image();
        requester.src   = CorticaDO.dotClickUrl + '?picUrl=' + escape(this.src) + '&pageUrl =' + escape(document.location.href) + 
        '&reqid='   + CorticaDO.requestId + '&pid=' + CorticaDO.publisherId + '&btype=' + CorticaDO.bannerType +
        '&campid='  + this.data.campaignId +
        '&advid='   + this.data.advertiserId +
        "&styleId=" + this.data.styleID + 
        "&behaviorId=" + this.data.behaviour +
        '&siteId='  + this.data.siteId;
    },
    /******* ______ ************************************************************************************/
    /** Get Element Position flow 2***/
    getOffsetSum: function(elem) {
        var top=0, left=0;
        while(elem) {
            top     = top + parseInt(elem.offsetTop);
            left    = left + parseInt(elem.offsetLeft);
            elem    = elem.offsetParent;
        }
        return {top: top, left: left};
    },
    /** Get Element Position flow 1***/
    getOffsetRect: function(elem) {
        var box         = elem.getBoundingClientRect();                                 // (1)
        var body        = document.body;                                                // (2)
        var docElem     = document.documentElement;
        var scrollTop   = window.pageYOffset || docElem.scrollTop || body.scrollTop;    // (3)
        var scrollLeft  = window.pageXOffset || docElem.scrollLeft || body.scrollLeft;
        var clientTop   = docElem.clientTop || body.clientTop || 0;                     // (4)
        var clientLeft  = docElem.clientLeft || body.clientLeft || 0;
        var top         = box.top +  scrollTop - clientTop;                             // (5)
        var left        = box.left + scrollLeft - clientLeft;
        return {top: Math.round(top), left: Math.round(left)};
    },
    /** Get Element Position Main ***/
    getOffsetElement: function(el){
        if (el.getBoundingClientRect)
            {return this.getOffsetRect(el);}
        else{return this.getOffsetSum(el);}
    },
    /** Get Element Style ***/
    getElStyle : function(el,styleProp){
        var value, defaultView = el.ownerDocument.defaultView;  
        if (defaultView && defaultView.getComputedStyle){// W3C standard way:
            styleProp = styleProp.replace(/([A-Z])/g, "-$1").toLowerCase();
            return defaultView.getComputedStyle(el, null).getPropertyValue(styleProp);
        }
        else{ 
            if (el.currentStyle) { // IE
                styleProp = styleProp.replace(/\-(\w)/g,function(str,letter){return letter.toUpperCase();});
                value = el.currentStyle[styleProp];
                if (/^\d+(em|pt|%|ex)?$/i.test(value)){// convert other units to pixels on IE
                    return (
                        function(value){
                            var oldLeft = el.style.left, oldRsLeft = el.runtimeStyle.left;
                            el.runtimeStyle.left = el.currentStyle.left;
                            el.style.left = value || 0;
                            value = el.style.pixelLeft + "px";
                            el.style.left = oldLeft;
                            el.runtimeStyle.left = oldRsLeft;
                            return value;
                        }
                    )(value);
                }
                return value;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
};
/***** OLD ****************************************************************************************/
function CorticaJSONscriptRequest(fullUrl,data){
    this.data       = data;
    this.fullUrl    = fullUrl;
    this.noCacheIE  = '&noCacheIE=' + (new Date()).getTime();
    this.headLoc    = document.getElementsByTagName("head").item(0);
    this.scriptId   = 'JscriptId' + CorticaJSONscriptRequest.scriptCounter++;
};
CorticaJSONscriptRequest.scriptCounter = 1;
CorticaJSONscriptRequest.prototype.buildScriptTag   = function(){
    this.scriptObj = document.createElement("script");
    this.scriptObj.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
    this.scriptObj.setAttribute("charset", "utf-8");
    this.scriptObj.setAttribute("src", this.fullUrl + '?' + this.data + this.noCacheIE);
    this.scriptObj.setAttribute("id", this.scriptId);
};
CorticaJSONscriptRequest.prototype.removeScriptTag  = function(){this.headLoc.removeChild(this.scriptObj);};
CorticaJSONscriptRequest.prototype.addScriptTag     = function(){this.headLoc.appendChild(this.scriptObj);};
/****************************************************************************************************/
/** Load / Calculate request string & Create script tag **/
function corticaInit(){
    if(arguments.callee.done){return;}  /* Preventing DC */
    // Make css
    corticaMakeCSS('.corticaBS{background-color:transparent;}.corticaAbs{position:absolute;}.corticaIS{image-rendering:optimizeQuality; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;}.corticaRB{width:100%;text-align:center;position:absolute;border:0;background-color:black;opacity:'+CorticaDO.opacity / 10 +';alpha(opacity='+CorticaDO.opacity+'0);}');
    // Get Publisher ID identifier:(script name with extention),name(parameter name)
    var pubID = CorticaDO.getParameterByName('searchBox.js','pid');
    if(typeof pubID != 'undefined' && pubID != '')
        {CorticaDO.publisherId = pubID;}
    // Start Auto Scanning for Visible Images
    setInterval("CorticaDO.corticaScan()", 200);
    // Set DC Flags
    arguments.callee.done = true;
    alreadyrunflag        = 1;
};
/** Common Functions *************************************************************************************/
function corticaMakeCSS(css){
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],style = document.createElement('style'),rules = document.createTextNode(css);
    style.type = 'text/css';
    if(style.styleSheet)
        {style.styleSheet.cssText = rules.nodeValue;}
    else{style.appendChild(rules);}
    head.appendChild(style);
};
/** Start Script *****************************************************************************************/
corticaInit();
```